# How can i get last iteration in javascript recursion?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I try to traverse dir with html5 file api (using drag folder) and have code like this:

```
function traverse(entry) {
if (entry.isDirectory) {
 dirReader = entry.createReader();
 dirReader.readEntries(function (entries) {
 for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
 someFoldersArray.push(entries[i]);
 traverse(entries[i]);
}})}
```

So, i want to send array of folders to server, when recursion will finished. How can i do it? dirReader.readEntries - this method is asynchronized.

Comment: I think i found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048861/callback-after-end-of-asynchronous-recursive-function